# Can s#arp-architecture/mySQL run under medium trust? Alternatives?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, hosting, s#arp-architecture

I am trying to get a simple prototype using ASP.NET S#arp-architecture (Sharp architecture) to run on a shared hosting site. This site runs in medium trust, which appears to give problems with this framework. At first I went off on a wild goose chase with the mySQL.data.dll, but the latest version already supports partially trusted callers.

The only way I found up until now is [this blogpost](http://paulwideman.com/softwareartist/2009/12/27/running-sharparchitecture-in-medium-trust/), which basically describes re-compiling everything from the ground up, starting with the various Castle components. Is this the only way to get this to work, and more importantly, *does this actually work?*

I have had some good experiences with S#arp-architecture, and since I only have a few days to build this prototype, I figured S#arp-architecture would be a good match. So, my options are to stick with SA, or on the other end of the spectrum to hand-roll an MVC/NH/mySQL application. Other suggestions (using NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC) are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-fold answer: re-compiling everything *does* work. I got a simple S#arp-architecture app to work at this hosting provider. I did not want to risk going over my prototype deadline however, so for the demo I built a very straightforward, simple app with (gasp!) straight ADO.NET.